# How to remove underlines and strikeouts in Adobe Reader 10.4.2 for Android 4?

Tags: adobe-reader

I tried out the new features of adding strikeouts and underlines to a PDF file, only to find that I can't remove these marks any more, because I can't find any such option! I even tried to copy the file in question to my PC, but the Adobe Reader for win7 doesn't have such functions as well. I only need a way to remove these marks I made, so it is OK whatever software or app you suggest me to use.